# pry - step command not stepping into method

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry

Say I have these lines of code in HashSample.rb

```
require "yaml"
require 'pry'
require 'pry-debugger'
require 'pry-nav'

def set_choice(choice)
    choice = "Choice456!@#"
end

hash_map = YAML.load(File.open("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/Event.yml"))
event = hash_map["Event"]
puts event.class
binding.pry
event_start_page_hash = event["RegForm"]["Start"]
event_visibility_hash = event_start_page_hash["EventVisibility"]
puts event_visibility_hash["Choice"]
event_visibility_choice = event_visibility_hash["Choice"]
event_visibility_choice = "IllegalChoice"
puts event_visibility_choice
# puts event_visibility_hash["Choice"]

# event_visibility_hash["Choice"] = "Choice123"
# puts event_start_page_hash["EventVisibility"]["Choice"]
# puts event["RegForm"]["Start"]["EventVisibility"]["Choice"]
binding.pry
set_choice(event_visibility_choice)
puts event_visibility_choice
puts event_visibility_hash["Choice"]

set_choice(event_visibility_hash["Choice"])
puts event_visibility_choice
puts event_visibility_hash["Choice"]
```

I then open a terminal and execute this file `ruby HashSample.rb`, it stopped at the first `binding.pry`, and, I typed pry command `next`, it jumped to the second `binding.pry` instead of executing the next line.
At the second `binding.pry`, I typed pry command `step`, but it ran to the end rather than stepping into the method `set_choice`.

According to https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger,
step: Step execution into the next line or method. Takes an optional numeric argument to step multiple times.
next: Step over to the next line within the same frame. Also takes an optional numeric argument to step multiple lines.

What was I doing wrong?

Edit: I am using `ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15 revision 40747) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]`, and:

1. `pry (0.10.1)`
2. `pry-debugger (0.2.3)`
3. `pry-nav (0.2.4)`
4. `pry-stack_explorer (0.4.9.2)`

Edit 1:
I tried uninstalling `pry-nav` and `pry-stack_explorer`, then `next` and `step` command works. Why do those gems have conflicts? I can't find anything about this kind of conflict in its documentation. Any clues?

Comment: What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: @JeremyRodi Please see my edit.

Comment: As a side note, what do you expect `set_choice` to do?

Comment: @JeremyRodi Just simply set value to the parameter, as what I defined it to. Well, it's just for a trial. I was wondering why `step` command didn't step into that method.

Comment: Did you uninstall each individually?  For example, uninstall one, test it, reinstall and uninstall the other, test it, and then uninstall both and test it.

Comment: It looks like `pry-nav` and `pry-debugger` both implement some commands.  Did you notice this?

Comment: @JeremyRodi I uninstalled both of them at one time. I haven't noticed pry-nav and pry-debugger implement the same commands, is that on github or some other documentation site?

Comment: I looked through the code for both on github: [`pry-nav/commands.rb`](https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav/blob/master/lib/pry-nav/commands.rb), [`pry-debugger/commands.rb`](https://github.com/nixme/pry-debugger/blob/master/lib/pry-debugger/commands.rb).

Comment: @JeremyRodi Oh yes. And according to [https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav](https://github.com/nixme/pry-nav), which says: `Using MRI 1.9.2+? Switch to pry-debugger. Using MRI 2+? Switch to pry-byebug. Same features as pry-nav but with faster tracing, breakpoints, and more.` I think it is suggesting using `pry-debugger` instead of `pry-nav`.

Comment: So... don't use both `pry-nav` and `pry-debugger` at the same time?

Comment: @JeremyRodi Yes, I think so.